# IIS 6.0 subdomains with host headers and non existent subdomains

Tags: iis-6

We have a wildcard A-Record pointing to our IP and have a number of sites running on IIS 6 with host headers and have a a wildcard SSL certificate for the domain so that each site can run under SSL.

For example: https://A.foo.com https:/B.foo.com https:/C.foo.com

Everything is working well but I noticed that when we type a non existent subdomain, say D.foo.com, it redirects to A.foo.com. Any idea why that is or how I can change that? I think we may have set up the A.foo.com site before we applied the wildcard A-record with our domain provider and before we had set up the SSL cert.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration of the default web site in IIS is to not filter on host headers. This web site will receive any requests that do not match one of the other web sites.

In its default state IIS 6's default web site will receive all requests to the server (by IP address) whatever the host header contains.